# SignalR in Delphi or C++Builder

Tags: delphi, signalr, c++builder

I need to send data in real time between Delphi/C++Builder apps placed in different PCs not connected in the same LAN, only using Internet.

My first approach was via DataSnap REST server but it is not practical due proxy and router problems. The configuration was too hard for the users plus that some people do not like to have a web server running in their machines opening the corresponding ports.

My second approach is using a server in the middle. I am checking SignalR technology that seems to fit very well. It is well solved for C# but I cannot find any information  about VCL, Delphi or C++ Builder.

Is there some library or do I need to work from scratch via WebSockets?

Is there another way to communicate VCL applications that run in separated PCs only connected to Internet?

Comment: look into websockets instead of SignalR. I have used SignalR extensively, but when trying to interoperate with Delphi, I discovered that the simplicity of SignalR (abstracting away WebSockets and other realtime communication) also made it incompatible with non JS and MS clients.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Apparently WebSockets is not included in Indy. Which other library can I use? Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets is one library, http://websockets.esegece.com/ is possibly similar

Comment: Thank you. I agree, it will be easier to use directly Websockets instead of SignalR for Delphi.

Comment: @kokokok: "*Apparently WebSockets is not included in Indy*" - not at this time, but it is on the TODO list.  Though WebSocket is not such a difficult protocol that it can't be implemented manually using the base Indy TCP components.

Answer (score 1):

/n Software has a WebSockets library - with C++Builder support.
https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ws/

Docs at https://cdn.nsoftware.com/help/IWF/bcb/

Download (there is a trial edition) at https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ws/download.aspx